# in internet explorer image often displayed very small and aligned to left at first time load

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

i have developed this website in wordpress and used supersized gallery for displaying images but after development clients said that he don’t want full background gallery but in center only so i have changed this function in re size so image will be displayed smaller than browser in center.

http://www.momenarchitects.com/gallery?gallery=4

but in internet explorer image often displayed very small and aligned to left at first time load.
i am trying to resolve this but not getting a clue how to fix.

any help would be appreciated……

i have changed this in re size function.

```
var browserwidth1 = $(window).width();
var browserheight1 = $(window).height();
var browserwidth = browserwidth1-(browserwidth1/3);
var browserheight = browserheight1 -(browserheight1/4);
```

and in css

```
#supersized img {
margin-left: 260px;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

please anyone help me....

Comment: Same Problem i m facing

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen in the past using some jQuery slideshow plug-ins and what-not. I'm guessing that after you refresh the page without clearing your cache the image appears as it should? 
This is a wild stab in the dark but check to see if the container the images are in is positioned in CSS. If not, position the container relative (or whatever suits) and see if that helps.
Also if the images are being populated to an unordered list, make sure the list item has some kind of width value. A width of 100% will tame a lot of IE list issues.

Hopefully that helps...?

Comment: thanks for your reply , Daniel
but i am resizing images on pages load and images are not of full back groung so i cant give them width:100%

i will try if first solution works .

Comment: i have tried position : relative but it does not worked for me.

Comment: Setting with 100% on a li solved a similar issue for me. Image loaded small on first load, but when refreshing the page, it was as it should be.